# Is there anyway in FME to create spatial features from data in Microsoft CRM?

Tags: fme-form

Is there anyway in FME to create spatial features from data in Microsoft CRM Online?

We have various CRM entities, which we'd like to put on the map. Some have addresses, some have UK OS NGR, some even have lat/long values.

I've checked the list of [FME formats](http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/#!) but can't find anything relating to Microsoft CRM

Somebody suggested going directly to the SQL Server tables, but this isn't possible as we're using CRM Online, so database connection

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the Dynamics CRM Web API to [query the service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_basicQuery) using a `GET` request? You could use Python in a startup script or a PythonCaller (depending on how you need to process the data), using the `adal` library [to authenticate](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/11/crm-web-api-using-python.html), then use something like `requests` or `urllib` to [send REST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) and get JSON back, which you could then [parse](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/parsingjson) to get out the bits of info you need, which you could then process with FME.

Comment: No, I hadn't  ... but I will now!

Comment: HTTPCaller with the query Chad points to will work (getting json response in return) then use the JSON transformers to parse the info you want into filtered attributes.